# how to troubleshoot android app errors in other devices

Tags: android, debugging, cordova, remote-debugging

I've made an Android app that it's causing a couple of problems to a few users. I can't reproduce those problems in my test devices (3 different devices with 3 different Android versions). I've been debugging the app with Eclipse and I don't see any kind of error where those users are having the problems.

The app is a Phonegap/jQuery Mobile app built with Eclipse.

How can I get the logs from those devices? I know the users so they would cooperate with anything I asked for to install or do.

**EDIT**

I'll give more info about the issues themselves. The app doesn't crash, it seems a jquery issue when changing pages, instead of showing the correct page the app gets stuck with the spinning thing. But it only happens in those 2 devices (Galaxy S4 and Note 3) that run Android 4.3. I've tried in other devices with Android 4.0.1, 4.2.2, 4.4.2 and no problems at all.

Oh, and I've already tried running the app in an emulator with 4.3, trying to replicate the S4 as close as possible in the emulation specs, and no problems there...

Comment: You can try testing them on emulator , you can find some devices using genymotion, or use sth like crashlytics (it sends crash reports) or ask your friends the crash case in detail.

Comment: You could use weinre to remote debug your customers' devices.

Comment: Or ask your users to enable debugging of their device and then run `adb logcat` just after the issue to get the logs. Given the issue you describe, I'd bet on a javascript error. (users would also need to install adb drivers from samsung)

Comment: @QuickFix thanks for your response. I also think it has to be a JS error. However, the error should be the same if I run the app in an emulator with the same version as the real devices, right? Because that's not happening, the app runs fine in the emulator with the same OS version as the phone...

Comment: Maybe samsung doesn't use the same webview as in the android image you  use in the emulator. On samsung devices I've seen, there was a modified default browser different from the google one. I'm not 100%sure, but I think the webview used in phonegap apps uses the device's default browser as an engine for the webview.